# How can I drop AVG_ROW_LENGTH clause in table's options?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have table with options:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=1024
```

which is rudiments of time when table had MyISAM storage engine. How can I to drop AVG_ROW_LENGTH? When I do `alter table crm_files_to_del ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;` I have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is common option for all tables. You cannot drop it.
Even system table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES contains this field.

For SHOW CREATE TABLE you can set 'NO_TABLE_OPTIONS' SQL modes. But in this case some other options won't be shown either.

From the reference:

> NO_TABLE_OPTIONS - Do not print MySQL-specific table options (such as
>   ENGINE) in the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE. This mode is used by
>   mysqldump in portability mode.

Comment: But why almost all my tables haven't this option?

Comment: As I understand, the storage engine (MyIsam or InnoDb) or MySQL itself, somehow adds that option to SHOW CREATE TABLE result.

Comment: Let me ask you - Why do you need it? If you need to drop this clause, then, I think, you should parse string and remove this clause.

Comment: I just want nice output of SHOW CREATE TABLE :)

Comment: Can you set 'NO_TABLE_OPTIONS' SQL mode? Will it help you?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

ALTER TABLE XXX
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 0;